# How to merge multiple SQL Server queries in to one

Tags: sql-server

How can you merge the following queries into one.

```
SELECT MID,
       Status,
       Owner1Fname,
       Owner1Lname,
       LegalName,
       DBAName,
       DBAEmail,
       DBAPhone,
       CorpPhone,
       SICCode
FROM   vw_merLeadData

SELECT replastname,
       replastname
FROM   vw_XXX_Page1

SELECT installdate,
       model,
       ownership,
       serialno
FROM   dbo.merequip
```

Comment: What should be the expected result ? You can query this as it ist e.g. via Ado and work with 3 resultsets.

Comment: Why would you want to? They all seem to have different columns. Is there any relationship between the tables?

Comment: The column count should be the same for you to be able to do that. If you of course mean list the query results one after another, if you want to list the results all together (basically next to each other) then you will need to do a few full joins.

Answer (score 1):

Like previous commenters I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this but then again I don't know what context you have for needing it,so I guess you have a good reason!Anyway, here's how you do it (apologies for the dud formatting):

```
SELECT MID,
   Status,
   Owner1Fname,
   Owner1Lname,
   LegalName,
   DBAName,
   DBAEmail,
   DBAPhone,
   CorpPhone,
   SICCode,
   replastname=NULL,
   replastname=NULL,
   installdate=NULL,
   model=NULL,
   ownership=NULL,
   serialno=NULL
   FROM   vw_merLeadData
   UNION ALL
   SELECT MID=NULL,
   Status=NULL,
   Owner1Fname=NULL,
   Owner1Lname=NULL,
   LegalName=NULL,
   DBAName=NULL,
   DBAEmail=NULL,
   DBAPhone=NULL,
   CorpPhone=NULL,
   SICCode=NULL,
   replastname=NULL,
   replastname=NULL,
   installdate=NULL,
   model=NULL,
   ownership=NULL,
   serialno=NULL       
FROM   vw_XXX_Page1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
MID=NULL,
   Status=NULL,
   Owner1Fname=NULL,
   Owner1Lname=NULL,
   LegalName=NULL,
   DBAName=NULL,
   DBAEmail=NULL,
   DBAPhone=NULL,
   CorpPhone=NULL,
   SICCode=NULL,
replastname=NULL,
   replastname=NULL,
installdate,
   model,
   ownership,
   serialno
 FROM   dbo.merequip
```

Basically you can union any tqo queries together as long as they have the same number of columns and the data type in each field is the same (or at least castable) as the corresponding fields in the other queries, hence all the NULLs which are just dummy columns.
Hope that helps.